# Struts2 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: exception, struts2

I have a problem with Struts2, in my ActionClass I declared an:

```
private Integer table; + setter and getter methods
```

then I have a form in my .jsp:

```
<s:form action="add-note" theme="simple">

            <s:select name="table" list="tablesList.{tableNr}" cssClass="tables" headerValue="-- Select table --" headerKey="-1"/>

</s:form>
```

But when I try to submit this form, I am getting a very strange exception:

> **Aug 19, 2011 3:17:28 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
>   WARNING: Error setting expression 'table' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@3052ab'
>   ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setTable" failed for object com.deveto.struts.actions.NotesAction@835dc6 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.deveto.struts.actions.NotesAction.setTable([Ljava.lang.String;)]**
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1285)
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1474)
>           at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
>           at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2245)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:77)
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2245)
>           at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
>           at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
>           at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
>           at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:209)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:160)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:288)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:199)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.deveto.struts.interceptors.LocaleInterceptor.intercept(LocaleInterceptor.java:62)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.deveto.struts.actions.NotesAction.setTable([Ljava.lang.String;)
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1226)
>           ... 56 more
>
> **/-- Encapsulated exception ------------\
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.deveto.struts.actions.NotesAction.setTable([Ljava.lang.String;)**
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1226)
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1474)
>           at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
>           at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2245)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:77)
>           at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2245)
>           at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
>           at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
>           at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
>           at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:209)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:160)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:288)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:199)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.deveto.struts.interceptors.LocaleInterceptor.intercept(LocaleInterceptor.java:62)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Sorry for the stack trace;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<select>` returns string value and you are trying to assign that value to an Integer variable `table`

Declare `table` as String (with getter/setter) and if you want to use its integer value then use the `parseInt()`method

```
 integerValue = Integer.parseInt(table)
```

Comment: you are right, I changed it to String, I thought that Struts should automatically convert all the values that comes from forms, depending on how developer sets it

Comment: Everything from a form comes back as a string. I can most definitely select a number from a select box and have struts2 convert it to an int. So if this is solved great but something is wrong with the reasoning.

Comment: This solution seems fishy. @hoss, take a look at what was being passed as the value of table in the request.

Answer (score 7):

I [posted this same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9377682/1148030) to another question earlier, but it could be relevant to this question also:

The NoSuchMethodException ... ([Ljava.lang.String;)] problem can be caused by having multiple attributes with the same name in the HTTP request.

If the case with multiple attributes with the same name is legitimate, you can handle multiple id values by changing setId(int id) to setId(String[] idArray) and parsing each array member string as an integer.

Make sure there is only one setId method (setId(String[] idArray)) in the action class. It seems some versions of struts/ognl (ognl 3.0.4?) can get confused if there are multiple methods with same name but different parameter types.

For example:

```
public void setId(String[] idArray) {
    for (String idString : idArray) {
       int id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
       ... handle different id values somehow ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's OGNL 3.0.4. I will try for the next time, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I second the part about having multiple methods with different parameters.  We were having the same issue.  Note that this issue didn't appear until we switched to Java 8.  Removing one of the methods (so that now only one method exists with a particular name) seemed to fix the issue.